# WPF: MediaElement doesn't display at runtime

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

This concerns WPF. The problem is that my MediaElement (actually a GIF) doesn't show up at runtime (so I only get an empty screen), even though it shows perfectly in the design mode. Before citing the code I note the following:

- The GIF-file in question has been added to the solution.
- Its BuildAction property is set to Resource (I've checked).
- When I replace the MediaElement by an Image element (and either use the same GIF-file or replace that source-file by a .png file), the image/GIF does display at runtime. Just not when it's used as a MediaElement.
- Closing and re-starting Visual Studio doesn't help.
- As I said (and just to emphasize, if I may), the GIF image does display in the design mode part of the screen - just not at runtime.

And here's the code:

```
     <Window x:Class="Testing.TestWindow" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
                xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Testing"
                mc:Ignorable="d"
                Title="TestWindow" WindowState="Maximized">
        <StackPanel>
            <MediaElement Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/untitled.gif" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="Visible" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Window>
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you simply make `Source="../../Images/untitled.gif"` it will work, assuming `Images` is a folder under your project root.

Comment: You are totally correct!

Comment: If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it as correct (tomorrow!). Would be even greater if you could add some explanation. Actually, I had tried Source="../Images/untitled.gif" (i.e. only one parent-operator at the beginning of the path!), because - at least that's what I thought and what the folder-tree in the solution explorer suggested - the Images folder is a *sibling* of the folder that contains the XAML-file -- and that failed. Now following your suggesting - i.e. using not one but two parent-operators in the path - it works, which is obviously a surprise to me.

Comment: I have no explanation other than _that's how they do it with MSDN SDK sample markup..._ :O)